# Displaying english alphabets in a div

Tags: javascript

```
for (var a = 0; a < 26; a++) {
                var alpha = $('<span class="alpha" />');
                alpha.addClass('alpha-' + (a % 2) + 1);
                $('.alphabets').append(alpha);
                $('.alpha').text(String.fromCharCode(65 + a));
            }
```

i am doing something like this and i know i am making mistake in

```
$('.alpha').text(String.fromCharCode(65 + a));
```

thats why i am getting "Z" in every span but i am not getting how to fix this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `$('.alpha')` (every element that is a member of the class *alpha*) to `alpha` (the specific element you just created and stored in that variable)

Comment: code snippet? its pretty self-explaining :-) just change the last line to  "alpha.text(String.fromCharCode(65 + a));"

Answer (score 1):

Your code overwrites the text of **all** `<span>`'s that happen to have the `alpha` *class*.

```
 $('.alpha').text(String.fromCharCode(65 + a));
```

You need to change your code so that it only alters the text of the last created `<span>`:

```
 alpha.text(String.fromCharCode(65 + a));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   $('.alphabets').append(alpha);
   $('.alpha').text(String.fromCharCode(65 + a));
```

Should be

```
   alpha.text(String.fromCharCode(65 + a));
   $('.alphabets').append(alpha);
```